# react-images-uploader: get file name or url of uploaded image back in react form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

I found a simple image uploader in react. The package uploads file in a simple clik. Is there a way to get url of uploaded file back in form so that i can insert image url in table with user id

[react image uploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-uploader)

Server side code

```
app.post('/multiple', upload.array('file'), function (req, res) {
const photos = req.files;
let data = [];
photos.map(p => data.push({
  name: `${API_URL}/uploads/${p.filename}`,
  orginal_name: `${p.originalname}`
}));
res.send({
  status: true,
  message: 'Photos are uploaded.',
  data: data
});
});
```

I am trying to use multer in node. but will it work with this package. how should i get "file" because here is no inpupt with name file. thanks for help

Frontend code

```
 <ImagesUploader
                url="http://localhost:5000/multiple"
                optimisticPreviews
                multiple={true}
                onLoadEnd: function(error: { message: string, ... }, response?: JSON)
                label="Upload a picture"
                />
```

It outputs following error

```
  Line 283:36:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  281 |                 optimisticPreviews
  282 |                 multiple={true}
> 283 |                 onLoadEnd: function(error: { message: string, ... }, response?: JSON)
      |                                    ^
  284 |                 label="Upload a picture"
  285 | 
  286 |
```

And also

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/multiple' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

As the CORS error pccurs, i couldnt check the response i receives

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

i commented the second line in node and allowed only 'http://localhost:3000' but still same error

Comment: Please, don't describe absolutely different problems in one question.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from a description of this library, it depends of your server.
When you handle an upload on the server, you can return an url of a new file and any other data.
And you can receive this data in callback

```
onLoadEnd: function(error: { message: string, ... }, response?: JSON)
```

They will be stored in 'response'

The code could be next:

A callback for an upload (if you use hooks).

```
const loadEnd = (error, response) => {
  if (!error) {
    const data = JSON.parse(response)
    // Here you can handle your data and save it to state. 
    // And after read it from state in function render().
  }
}
```

You render your element to upload.

```
<ImagesUploader
  url="http://localhost:5000/multiple"
  optimisticPreviews
  multiple={true}
  onLoadEnd: {loadEnd}
  label="Upload a picture"
  />
```

Comment: thanks for your help, can you elaborate it little more. i m new in react. how i get array of file urls in a filedarray so that i can retriece back in node. i m not familiarize with callbacks and all

Comment: Provide your source code in your question, please. Then I can try to help you.

Comment: i just went through the package information provided by the author. and i found Example server  code as well. Bit if i get only the filenames back then i use it otherwise i will try something else. so i m about to get a rough idea on how to proceed

Comment: Seems there is only code on NodeJS, post your ReactJS code also, please

Comment: Yes i updated. Now the images are being creating. Just want ti save url array